# Disable auto rotation screen - Android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set android show vertical orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119606/how-to-set-android-show-vertical-orientation)

I'm trying to disable auto rotation when I run my application in Android.
Maybe, I should add a line code in AndroidManifest.xml 
Anyone know How can I do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119606/how-to-set-android-show-vertical-orientation

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add something like `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` or `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: If it is the case you can also set it to "landscape"

Comment: can ny one tell me how to eanble only landscape and potrait mode only (restrict reverse landscape and reverse potrait) at the same time??? Please help..its urgent

Comment: @himanshu You'd better create your own question..

Answer (score 4):

add a

```
android:screenOrientation="<mode>"
```

attribute to your activity.

see modes here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

for portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `android:screenOrientation` attribute to your `<activity />` tag:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
          ... >
```

For further information and a list of possible values visit the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen).

Answer (score 1):

You can make your Activity stay in a single orientation mode by adding the code suggested in the other answers. A more complete way of dealing with this is here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

When you change orientation what you're doing is changing the app configuration. Look under the heading of "Handling the configuration change yourself" section to override the default behaviour.